how is Mobius inversion derived in the first place?
I kind of understand how to prove Mobius inversion, but is there any hint regarding how Mobius came up with this idea in the first place?  Specifically, are there any related observations that can "naturally" lead to this inversion formula?

It is naturally related to inclusion-exclusion.

Just solve $1\ast\mu=\varepsilon$ with this. As to what Möbius personally did first, that's a question for HSM SE.

It arises naturally in the product formula for the Euler Totient function $\varphi(n)=n\prod_{d|n}\left(1-\frac 1p\right)$ as the coefficients in the expansion of the product [without the zeros for where prime factors are not distinct, which are not relevant to this expansion]. Apostol's Introduction to Analytic Number Theory Chapter 2 gives the basic theory of the function in a context in which it is often used.

This seems like a good historical article: The Mobius Function and Mobius Inversion by Carl Lienert (PDF), published as part of TRIUMPHS, "Transforming Instruction in Undergraduate Mathematics via Primary Historical Sources". If I'm reading it correctly, Möbius did not actually come up with the Möbius inversion formula (only the Möbius function), and it was Edmond Laguerre?

You could have discovered the Möbius inversion formula.  Let's look at a simple example of how.  Suppose we wanted to compute the the Euler $\varphi$ function:
$$\varphi(12) = \sum_{n\in\{1\ldots 12\}} [ n \bot 12 ]$$
Here, $f(n) = [ n\bot 12]$ is the function that is $1$ if $n$ is relatively prime to $12$, and zero otherwise.
That's one way to compute $\varphi(12)$: it's $$\underbrace{1}_1+0+0+0+\underbrace{1}_5+0+\underbrace{1}_7+0+0+0+\underbrace{1}_{11}+0= 4.$$
Unfortunately $[ n \bot 12]$ is somewhat hard to compute and quite hard to manipulate analytically.
But another way to compute $\varphi(12)$ goes like this:  A number is relatively prime to $12$ unless it is divisible by some factor of $12$ other than $1$.  Counting the numbers in $1\ldots 12$ that are divisible by some factor $d$ is trivial: it's simply $\frac{12}d$.   So let's try counting the numbers divisible by each factor of 12 and see if we can put together the subtotals somehow.

Of the numbers from $1\ldots 12$, all $12$ are multiples of $1$
$6$ are multiples of $2$
$4$ are multiples of $3$
$3$ are multiples of $4$
$2$ are multiples of $6$
One is a multiple of $12$

Of course, this overcounts ridiculously.  We counted the number $12$ itself six times!  To do it correctly, we need to proceed as follows:

We start with the twelve multiples of $1$.  Then from this we should subtract:
Multiples of $2$
Multiples of $3$
We already subtracted the multiples of $4$ in step 2, so don't do it again
We already subtracted the multiples of $6$ twice, so we should add them back once to make up for double-counting them
We also subtracted the multiples of 12 twice, but then corrected the double-counting in the previous step, so we shouldn't count them again

This gives us:
$$
\begin{array}{crl}
& \varphi(12) = \\
 & 1\cdot 12 & \text{multiples of $1$} \\
+ & -1\cdot 6 & \text{multiples of $2$} \\
+ & -1 \cdot 4 & \text{multiples of $3$} \\
+ & 0\cdot 3 & \text{already counted multiples of $4$} \\
+ & 1\cdot 2 & \text{adjust for double-counted multiples of $6$ }\\
+ & 0\cdot 1 & \text{already counted $12$}
\end{array}
$$
Hey look, the answer is $\varphi(12) = 12-6-4+2 = 4$.  And instead of dealing with the difficult $f(n) = [n \bot 12]$ we dealt instead with the simplest possible function $g\left(\frac nd\right) = \frac nd$.  The cost was that we had to include those $\{-1, 0, 1\}$ multipliers to keep track of the double-counting.  But those are not too bad, and they are always the same for any $g$ function, because they depend only on the prime factorization of $d$.
The $\{-1, 0, 1\}$ multipliers are exactly the Möbius function, and the Möbius inversion formula is just equating two different ways to count something.

Thanks for the reply!  I am a bit confused about the 3 functions f, g, phi here.  I get that phi(n) is sum of g(n/d) multiplied by corresponding Mobius function, and phi is the sum of f as well, then how is g expressed in terms of phi?  I guess my question is, there are 2 related functions f, g in Mobius inversion, but here there are 3 functions (it seems to me that you are showing how phi can be computed in 2 different ways), can you clarify how this "inversion" works here?

I'll try to come back later to address this.

This answer shows that $\phi(n) = \sum_{d|n} \mu(d) n/d$, i.e. that $f(n) = \sum_{d|n} \mu(d) g(n/d)$, where $f$ is the phi function and $g$ is the identity function. This is good motivation for the Möbius function $\mu$ and for sums of the form $\sum_{d|n} \mu(d) g(n/d)$. The Möbius inversion would then say that $g(n) = \sum_{d|n} f(n)$, i.e. in this case that $n = \sum_{d|n} \phi(n)$ — this part seems to be missing currently.

Yes, it's a very incomplete answer in many ways. I think it is fixable but the U.S. tax filing deadline is coming up so my head has been full.  Please go ahead and improve it any way you think of, perhaps by voting to delete.
